# Items are logged in the reverse of expected order in RxJS

Tags: javascript, rxjs

This behavior isn't bad in my particular use-case but it is very unexpected and I'd like to understand why this is happening.

I have the following code running in a sandbox (imported RxJS 6.6.0):

```js
const Rx = rxjs;
const {map,tap, merge, take} = Rx.operators;

const sub = new Rx.ReplaySubject();

sub.next(1);
sub.pipe(
  tap(x => {
    if (x < 50) sub.next(x*2);
  })
)
.subscribe({
  next(x) {
    console.info('Subscriber A', x)
  },
  complete() {
    console.log('Subscriber A -- Complete!')
  }
});
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.6.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

I might be doing this entirely the wrong way, but I want intermediate functions to push items back into the original Subject/Observable while also emitting the original item(s) (a feedback loop of sorts). This is the output I'm getting:

```
Subscriber A64
Subscriber A32
Subscriber A16
Subscriber A8
Subscriber A4
Subscriber A2
Subscriber A1
```

I would've expected "Subscriber A1" first but it seems like `next` is adding items to the beginning of the stream instead of the end? Can anyone help make sense of this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The emitted value won't reach the subscriber before it has gone through all the pipes, and since you are calling next inside of your tap, this new value emitted gets handled before the previous tap finishes and thus reaches the subscriber first. Repeat for every calls of next.

Some visualization:

```js
    const Rx = rxjs;
    const { map, tap, merge, take } = Rx.operators;

    const sub = new Rx.ReplaySubject();

    sub.next(1);
    sub.pipe(
        tap(x => {
            console.info("before next in tap x = ", x);
            if (x < 50) sub.next(x * 2);
            console.info("after next in tap x = ", x);
        })
    )
        .subscribe({
            next(x) {
                console.info('Subscriber A', x)
            },
            complete() {
                console.log('Subscriber A -- Complete!')
            }
        });
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.6.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah ha! `next()` is operating synchronously. I thought all RxJS operations were inherently async. When I wrap the `next()` call in a Promise I get exactly the behavior I was expecting. So when the "item" exits the `pipe` is when `next` will finally return? Is there any more documentation on the behavior? Official docs say very little about `next()` or a least it's not well-organized.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you have a recursive effect happening due to the `sub.next()` being used inside the `tap()` operator. So it fills the call stack until it reaches the condition limit, then returns the stack from last-to-first.

However, if you need to have an accumulation effect inside an observable then `scan()` is the more optimal choice. It behaves like `Array.reduce()` but it runs the inner function for each emitted value. Then `takeUntil()` handles the conditional limit.

```js
const Rx = rxjs;
const {interval} = Rx;
const { scan, tap, takeWhile, startWith} = Rx.operators;

const double$ = interval(1).pipe(
  scan((acc, cur)=>acc*2,1),
  startWith(1),
  takeWhile(value=>value<50, true),
  tap(value=>console.info(`Subscriber A${value}`)),
).subscribe();
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@6.6.0/bundles/rxjs.umd.min.js"></script>
```